# Programmatically add a hyperlink button to outlook 2007

Tags: vba, vbscript, outlook, outlook-2007

I am adding a toolbar to Outlook.

The toolbar will have one button on it.

This button, when pressed, will open up a web site.

I've created the button & toolbar no problem, but cannot work out how to add the hyperlink?

```
  Set oTBar = oView.Add("toolbarname")
  oTBar.Position = 1
  oTBar.Visible = true

  Set oButton = OTBar.Controls.Add
  With oButton
      .Caption = "Click here!"
      .Style = 3
      .HyperlinkType = 1
      .FaceId = 1707     
   End with
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haha!

You need to add it as the tooltip:

```
  .ToolTipText  = "http://your_url"
```